# Steps of tf.summary.* operations in TensorBoard are always 0

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, tensorboard

When I'm training my model with TensorFlow 2.3, I want to visualize some intermediate tensors calculated using the weight in the computation graph of my customized `tf.keras.layers.Layer`.

So I use `tf.summary.image()` to record these tensors and visualize them as images like this:

```
class CustomizedLayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
    def call(self, inputs, training=None):
        # ... some code ...
        tf.summary.image(name="some_weight_map", data=some_weight_map)
        # ... some code ...
```

But in TensorBoard, no matter how many steps passed, there is only one image of step 0 shown.

And I tried to set the parameter ***step*** of `tf.summary.image()` to the value obtained from `tf.summary.experimental.get_step()`:

```
tf.summary.image(name="weight_map", data=weight_map, step=tf.summary.experimental.get_step())
```

And update the step by calling **tf.summary.experimental.set_step** from a customized Callback using a tf.Variable like codes shown below:

```
class SummaryCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
def __init__(self, step_per_epoch):
    super().__init__()
    self.global_step = tf.Variable(initial_value=0, trainable=False, name="global_step")
    self.global_epoch = 0
    self.step_per_epoch = step_per_epoch
    tf.summary.experimental.set_step(self.global_step)

def on_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
    self.global_step = batch + self.step_per_epoch * self.global_epoch
    tf.summary.experimental.set_step(self.global_step)  
    # whether the line above is commented, calling tf.summary.experimental.get_step() in computation graph code always returns 0.
    # tf.print(self.global_step)

def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
    self.global_epoch += 1
```

This Callback's instance is passed in the argument ***callbacks*** in `model.fit()` function.

But the value `tf.summary.experimental.get_step()` returned is still 0.

The TensorFlow document of "`tf.summary.experimental.set_step()`" says:

> when using this with @tf.functions, the step value will be captured at the time the function is traced, so changes to the step outside the function will not be reflected inside the function unless using a tf.Variable step.

Accroding to the document, I am already using a Variable to store the steps, but it's changes are still not reflected inside the function (or keras.Model).

Note: My code produces expected results in TensorFlow 1.x with just a simple line of `tf.summary.image()` before I migrate it to TensorFlow 2.

So I want to know if my approach is wrong in TensorFlow 2?

In TF2, how can I **get training steps inside the computation graph**?

Or there is other solution to **summarize tensors (as scalar, image, etc.) inside a model in TensorFlow 2**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this issue has been reported on Github repository of Tensorflow: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/43568

This is caused by using **tf.summary** in model while **tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard** callback is also enabled, and the step will always be zero. The issue reporter gives a temporary solution.

To fix it, inherit the **tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard** class and overwrite the **on_train_begin** method and **on_test_begin** method like this:

```
class TensorBoardFix(tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard):
"""
This fixes incorrect step values when using the TensorBoard callback with custom summary ops
"""

def on_train_begin(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TensorBoardFix, self).on_train_begin(*args, **kwargs)
    tf.summary.experimental.set_step(self._train_step)


def on_test_begin(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(TensorBoardFix, self).on_test_begin(*args, **kwargs)
    tf.summary.experimental.set_step(self._val_step)
```

And use this fixed callback class in **model.fit()**:

```
tensorboard_callback = TensorBoardFix(log_dir=log_dir, histogram_freq=1, write_graph=True, update_freq=1)
model.fit(dataset, epochs=200, callbacks=[tensorboard_callback])
```

This solve my problem and now I can get proper step inside my model by calling **tf.summary.experimental.get_step()**.

(This issue may be fixed in later version of TensorFlow)